# How to copy specific rows from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL database and working on a basic database. I have multiple tables in my database which have lots of column data in common so instead of inserting values in all tables, I'm trying to add values in one table and then copy this data to other tables without inserting them manually. I'm trying this code.

```
select user_id,user_name,user_email,user_adrees,user_phone_no,user_DOB,User_blood_group,
user_Diasease,user_gender from user_info where user_role='Donner' 
AND user_id IN (select id from donner_info Group by id having(COUNT(id)=0));
```

I'm trying to use this condition to copy rows that are not already available in the donner_info table.

`AND user_id IN (select id from donner_info Group by id having(COUNT(id)=0));`

if I remove above condition from code, then it works and copies data from user_info to donner_info, but the only problem is that it will duplicate the data in donner_info table, which means when I will copy data from user_info table then it will copy all the new data plus the old data which is already copied to donner_info table before and there will be lots of duplicated rows in donner_info table.

I know how to delete duplicated rows, but I don't want duplicated rows to copy, I only want to copy new rows which are not already present in donner_info.

Comment: Why are you copying data around? Why not use JOINS to access it where it is?

Comment: in local host. just learning basics of sql